# What is a “pocket door”?

Tags: pocket-door

Outside of the USA, most people have never heard of the term “pocket door”. Can you explain what this is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pocket door is a door that slides into the wall as opposed to opening in or out as a regular door would.

A good comparison would be the sliding doors as most mega-marts or large stores that slide open when you walk towards them or if you're a fan of "Star Trek: The Next Generation". The doors throughout the ship are "pocket doors" (except our pocket doors don't make the neat hissing sound when the open).

Comment: So tempted to post a question about install custom pneumatic pocket doors in my building...

Comment: @JeffFerland well with a motion sensor, a vacuum pump and a piston it shouldn't be too hard...

Comment: If the track places the door outside the wall instead of inside (as most of the sliding store doors seem to be with their "glass walls"), then it's a "barn door" (not to be confused with "barn door" as used in stage and studio lighting equipment).

Answer (score 10):

A picture being worth 1000 words,

This is a pocket door:

[image]