# In the UK, where do I buy a “pocket door” kit from?

Tags: pocket-door

“[pocket doors](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/214/what-is-a-pocket-door)” are common the USA, however they are hardly never seen in the UK, so how do I buy one in the UK?

Comment: Thanks for the post - I never knew that they were called that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SDS London sells them](http://www.sdslondon.co.uk/sliding-pocket-door-kits/pocket-hideaway-kit-1067-mm-door-weight-90-kg.html).